# How to remove response headers when sending a json response in php?

Tags: php, json, response-headers

I am making an ajax request to a php page e.g page1.php. In page1.php I have a `header("Location:page2.php?password=1234")` code which redirects to page2.php with the password as a GET parameter. page2.php gives a json response. 
The problem is that when I do inspect element and check the resources in Safari browser, I am able to see the location page2.php?password=1234" in the response header part.
This is a security issue. Please suggest how can I remove the response headers when sending the json response? I am using PHP 5.2.6.

Comment: What is the purpose of that password? And why do you do the redirect anyway?

Comment: This is looking incorrect way for authentication ??

Comment: "with the password as a GET parameter" PLEASE tell me it's not in plain text and you're using SSL.

Comment: by issuing this header, you are telling the browser where to go. The browser needs to know it in order to fetch data from there. But since browser knows it, there is nothing preventing user from finding it. End of "security". Full stop.

Answer (score 0):

Why just don't use SESSION for logged user? Or plain simple Cookie?

Comment: I cant use sessions. I need a way to remove location in the response header.

Comment: @sangman: if you need to redirect you have 3 ways: Location, meta-refersh, javascript solution. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than redirecting to the second page, you could query it from the first page, and display its output.

Assuming your setup supports it, the easiest way is probably to include the following in `page1.php`:

```
readfile('http://yoursite.org/page2.php?password=1234');
```

Comment: It is a requirement. i have to have a intermediate page

Comment: Well, you still have an intermediate page in this case, but it hides the fact that it uses page2.php from the client.  There won't be a way to secure this setup from javascript though.  Anyone can read the javascript source, and see that an ajax call is made to page1.php.  They could then visit that page in a browser, get forwarded to page2.php?password=1234, and see the password anyway.

Comment: I get the password as a POST in page1.php then I append it to the page2.php?password=$_POST['passwd']. I need a way to remove the location in the response header

Answer (score 0):

as a poor man defense, you could use some kind of crypt functions (md5, sha1, crc32) to generate hash from password and transfer it instead of password. Though, it is better to redo whole system to avoid it.

This workaround does not answer your question, though.